# I am struggling to add multiple variables (as points/point graphics). I have created one which works, but can't add more

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create multiple markers. I've created one that works, but when I try to add more it won't work.
If you could lead me in a direction with adding the other markers successfully that would be great.

```
                // Create a point geometry (this is the location of the "JOHN BARSBY COMMUNITY SCHOOL" school)
            var point = new Point({
                x: -13798269.7982,
                y: 6300212.72922,
                spatialReference: { wkid: 102100 }
            });

    var point1 = new Point({
                x: -13798469.7982,
                y: 6301512.72922,
                spatialReference: { wkid: 102100 }
            }); 


    // Create a graphic and add the symbol and geometry to it
            var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
                symbol: pictureSymbol,
                geometry: point,
    attributes: {Name: " JOHN BARSBY COMMUNITY SCHOOL", Phone: "250-753-8211", URL: "http://jb.schools.sd68.bc.ca/"},
                popupTemplate: infoTemplate,
            });

            var pointGraphic1 = new Graphic({
                symbol: pictureSymbol,
                geometry: point,
                attributes: {Name: " JOHN BARSBY COMMUNITY SCHOOL", Phone: "250-753-8211", URL: "http://jb.schools.sd68.bc.ca/"},
                popupTemplate: infoTemplate,
            });

             // Add the graphics to the view's graphics layer
            view.graphics.add(pointGraphic, pointGraphic1);

    });
```

Comment: What plugin/library are you using to create these graphics? Can you create a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example?

Comment: can you tell us what library you're using? what are you trying to accomplish overall?

Comment: You are calling the same `point` from both your pointgraphics. Shouldn't pointgraphic1 have point1 as its geometry?

Comment: "*it won't work*" isn't very descriptive. We need to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve and exactly what's wrong with the current solution (errors, unexpected results, etc.) The code that you've shown is only a fragment and the actual problem may be elsewere. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help us understand the problem. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55658970/edit) your question to include the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

Use `point1` in the `pointGraphic1` definition. Both graphics are using the same point.